# SAP Spartacus - How to wrap an element around 2 custom components in a slot?

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to obtain the following HTML / template structure on a page in Spartacus (version 3 as of writing this question):

```
<cx-page-layout class="SomePageTemplate">
    <cx-page-slot position="SomeContentSlot">

        <app-header-component></app-header-component>
        <!-- I am just trying to add this "row" div -->
        <div class="row">
            <app-left-component></app-left-component>
            <app-right-component></app-right-component>
        </div>

    </cx-page-slot>
</cx-page-layout>
```

I would like to wrap `app-left-component` and `app-right-component` in a `<div class="row">...</div>`.

However, I have some **constraints**:

- I cannot move `app-left-component` and `app-right-component` inside `app-header-component`
- I cannot create a parent component and add the 2 components to it, and then do something like:

**HTML:**

```
    <app-left-component></app-left-component>
    <app-right-component></app-right-component>
```

**TS:**

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-parent-of-left-right-component',
      templateUrl: '...',
      styleUrls: ['...'],
      host: {'class': 'row'} // that's the important line here
    })
    export class ParentOfLeftRightComponent { }
```

Other **notes**:

- The custom Angular components are added to the page slot by providing a CMS component configuration to the `ConfigModule` I.e. by mapping the components' names to their respective `flexTypes` (as indicated in the [docs](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/)).
- Current state of my HTML:

```
<cx-page-layout class="SomePageTemplate">
    <cx-page-slot position="SomeContentSlot">
        <app-header-component></app-header-component>
        <app-left-component></app-left-component>
        <app-right-component></app-right-component>
    </cx-page-slot>
</cx-page-layout>
```

Is there any "Spartacus" way of doing this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this line a typo or wrong ?

```
 <app-header-component> </app- left -component>
```

This should be possible

```
    <app-header-component>
      <!-- I am just trying to add this "row" div -->
      <div class="row">
        <app-left-component></app-left-component>
        <app-right-component></app-right-component>
      </div>
    </app-header-component>
```

Comment: Hi @Felix, thanks for your answer. That line (`<app-header-component></app-left-component>`) had a typo indeed - I corrected the answer. Unfortunately I cannot move app-left-component and app-right-component inside app-header-component (as stated in the "constraints" part of my question). I need to find a solution to wrap the 2 components ("left" and "right") without adding them to a "parent" component.